# Do I have to pay $12.99 to accept someone's challenge?

Tags: ios, game-center

This is awkward. Some random person has sent me a challenge. Except, instead of an "Accept" button, it's "$12.99".

Is this a bug? A scam or what?

[image: $12.99? No thank you.]

*The lack of profile pictures was me not giving the Game Center app time to load them.*

Comment: Do you know the person who sent you this challenge? If not, I would guess that it's the creator of that app trying to drum up some business — perhaps not a scam, but just north of one.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, this guy seems to be a random who has somehow got my email (or appeared in his "Suggested Friends" list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That 13 dollar fee is the price of the app your opponent is challenging you on. Make sure you have the app installed, and if not, search to see how much it is. That is the most probable answer to your problem. If you still need help, search through this [forum post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6), as it should cover any additional questions you may have.

Comment: Do you have any credible source? (Or did you just click and then it asks you whether to purchase an app or not)?

Comment: What iOS app costs $12.99?  Sounds like a scam integrated into Game Center to make people buy it, if this is true.

Comment: This has happened to me before but I've never seen a $13 app done with this

Comment: @aytimothy I've found this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6) and  [forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1057510) that seems to indicate that the amount is the price of the application you're being challenged with.

Comment: @Frank I've purchased iOS games that cost $30. Just because the most popular model out there is free to play doesn't mean all games follow that model.

Comment: @Frank Here's some examples of games that were $10 to $30 when they first came out. Ghost Trick, The Phoenix Wright Trilogy, Final Fantasy 1-6, Final Fantasy Tactics, Chrono Trigger, Banner Saga.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I have fixed the answer.